# Some of my controller actions are 404ing in my ASP.NET Core app

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

This is an interesting problem I'm having. My controller is like

```
    public HomeController()
    {
        TaskRepo = new ArchiveTasksRepository();
    }

    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("tasks/all/count")]
    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public ActionResult NumberArchiveTasks()
    {
        return Json(TaskRepo.GetTaskCount());
    }
```

and I have a bunch of other endpoints like the `NumberArchiveTasks` one. This is for an ASP.NET Core app that I wrote following a tutorial. All the endpoints work when I run the app locally. But when I deploy to IIS on a remote server, the `Index` one works while the others don't; they 404. I'm not sure if it's the `HttpGet` attribute, the fact that I'm using `ActionResult` instead of `IActionResult`, or what exactly it could be. Maybe something else. Any idea how I could figure this out, or should I just guess-and-check until it works?

Comment: What is the URL you are trying which returns 404?

Comment: Could it be because the route you specified is relative and doesn't start with a slash?

Comment: @benjrb it would be an xhr `GET` request to `http://example.com/tasks/all/count`, for example. However, `http://example.com` seems to correctly hit the `Index` action, which is the part I'm trying to figure out. In the JavaScript it is called through the URL `"tasks/all/count"`.

Comment: @user7127000 you missed the controller name in your URL. I think you need example.com/home/tasks/all/count?

Comment: @benjrb that shoudln't matter because my startup has `template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");`

Comment: show us your routes how they are defined in your startup.cs

Comment: @DOMZE here you go https://github.com/jamkin/archivedash/blob/master/LrcArchiveDash/Startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

Your default route will match /home/numberarchivetasks, I believe. Your route attribute doesn't start with a slash so it will be relative, which means it likely is something like /home/tasks/all/count - have you tried that?

I recommend putting your action in a TasksController (with attribute [Route("[controller]")]) and then the action can have a relative route off of that.